# How to detect category of a message using MailCore2

Tags: ios, email, mailcore2

I am integrating MailCore2 in my app. I am trying to get category of Email (Such as primary / social/etc). How could I get that using MailCore2??

I am using following code to initiate Folder Fetch Operation,

```
MCOIMAPFetchFoldersOperation *fetchOp2 = [self.imapSession fetchSubscribedFoldersOperation];
[fetchOp2 start:^(NSError *error , NSArray *folders){

    NSLog(@"%@",folders);
if(!error)
{
    for (NSString *folder in folders) {
        NSLog(@"%@",folder);
    }
}
else{
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}

}];
```

Comment: I think `Line#4` should be `NSLog(@"%@",folders);`